# Google Profile Photo "certain types of Google Accounts can't change photos"

Tags: google-drive, account-management, profile-picture

I am trying to change my profile photo for a Google Drive account, and I know how to do so and have done so before. However, for some reason, whenever I try to change it, either it says there's an "error in saving" or when through the "Personal Info" page, it says some types of Google accounts can't change profile photos. However, I have changed the photo for this account before, and have had no problems. What could be the explanation and how do I change my photo?

Comment: I've had this problem as well, with both types.

Answer (score 1):

provided pictures for debugging from **[@米凯乐](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/206474/%E7%B1%B3%E5%87%AF%E4%B9%90)**

- [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtOmD.jpg)
- [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zYmi.png)

---

### CONCLUSION:

While I had no issues with the first image:

> [image]

The second image resulted always in various errors, one of which was:

> [image]

And I was unable to change it unless the image was resized. This was caused mostly because of Google's "pick size tool" (although it looks like smart/intuitive tool) can't handle resizing (upscaling/downscaling) of the image beyond the specific range of threshold. Therefore:

> [image]

Also image should be between 10KB - 5MB. References:

- https://www.canva.com/sizes/google/
- http://freshtakeoncontent.com/google-plus-image-sizes/
- https://postcron.com/en/blog/social-media-image-dimensions-sizes/
- https://www.vieodesign.com/blog/social-media-image-sizes-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Is this a G Suite account? If so, there are [Directory Settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7326921?hl=en) that might need to be changed that will allow users to change their photo.